# my godaddy hosted orchard website is thrownig The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

Tags: iis-7, orchardcms, web-hosting

My godaddy hosted orchard website is throwing: 
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred"

Any one faced this issue?

Comment: Most likely cause is misconfiguration. Did you change anything on your site before it started throwing this error?

Comment: its running on my local machine, and we hosted it in azure cloud its  also running, [styfox @ azure](http://styfox.azurewebsites.net) and the godaddy hosted is at [Styfox @ godaddy](http://styfox.com)

Comment: Which one throwing an error? If both are than first look in your local IIS and ASP log files. P.S. A syntax error in any of the main files/includes may cause this behaviour.

Comment: in local and at azure its running fine. but its throwing error on godaddy hosting

Comment: Check the log file in App_Data/Logs.

Comment: I am not seeing any error on styfox.com.  What page is the error on?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error message, but I am not running Orchard. I had moved a ASP.NET 4.5 site from a hosted Rackspace server to GoDaddy. I found that the problem was related to a  tag in the web.config; similar to this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Once I removed the  tag I stopped getting the error. Since this app was built by someone else, not sure if I will need to figure out how to re-insert the tag or not.

Hope this might help someone else who stumbles upon this question via Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, check the .NET version you're loading Orchard on. If your using v1.6 then you need .NET 4.0.

This happened to me, when I updated a .Net 2.0 website to Orchard. The hosting company the Client was using is Shared hosting and all my testing environments ran the site fine. It wasn't until I asked the Client to ask there hosting company what version they were using, that the penny dropped. Also check your permissions with the App_Data folder if your using SqlCE.

Answer (score 0):

This may have cause by the permission settings of App_Data folder. You may need to give write access to this folder.